# How to set button next to input field in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have form group with label and input field. I would like to place the button next to the input field on the same line. Here is example of my code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-8"><label for="date">Date:</label>
    <div class="input-group date"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="date" id="date" value="" placeholder="Enter Date"><span class="input-group-append"><span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4 pt-4"><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Reset Date</button></div>
</div>
```

In my example you will see that button is not on the same line as input field. Is there a way to get them on the same line (vertical height)? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-8"><label for="date">Date:</label>
    <div class="input-group date"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="date" id="date" value="" placeholder="Enter Date"><span class="input-group-append"><span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span></span>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" style="margin-left:5px">Reset Date</button>
    </div>
  </div>
 
</div>
```

Alternative:

You can give a button a margin-top like `style="margin-top:10px"`

Comment: Is this the only way? To put button in the `input-group` or there is other way as well? I'm asking this because if button is in the input group, when I click on the button calendar will open in that case. My .input-group and  .date div section is designed to open every time user clicks on the input field or calendar icon. With your example button is part of that section.

Comment: @espresso_coffee, you can do the alternative way by setting margin style="margin-top:10px"

Answer (score 0):

You could change your markup a little bit and use the `.form-inline` class

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group"><label class="mr-2" for="date">Date:</label>
    <div class="input-group date mr-2"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="date" id="date" value="" placeholder="Enter Date"><span class="input-group-append"><span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group"><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Reset Date</button></div>
</div>
```